# Pandas DataFrame apply only returning first column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to search for the text 'Total' across all columns in a row in a dataframe.

```
def f(row):
    for i in range(0,len(row))
        if re.search('Total', row[i]) is None:
            return False
        else:
            return True

data['newColumn'] = data.apply(f, axis=1)
```

Is it correct to assume function f is called once per row in the dataframe?

What happens is my newColumn only gets the totals from the first column in the dataframe even though len(row) actually returns the correct amount of columns.

Adding in a print(row[i]) also prints out the correct values. But the assignment to the new column is only True where Total is in the text of the first column. I also do not seem to be able to iterate the row passed into the function. It has type Series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a return statement for both cases inside the loop, the function will always return after the first column.

Try this instead:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"row_1": ["foo", "Total", "bar"], 
                   "row_2": ["Total", "foo", "bar"]})
df["is_total_in_row"] = df.apply(
    lambda row : "Total" in list(row), axis=1)
print(df)
```

Returns

```
      row_1  row_2  is_total_in_row
 0    foo  Total             True
 1  Total    foo             True
 2    bar    bar            False
```

Answer (score 1):

Borrowed sample data set from @Sumido:

```
In [43]: df['newColumn'] = df.select_dtypes(['object']).sum(1).str.contains('Total')

In [44]: df
Out[44]:
   row_1  row_2  newColumn
0    foo  Total       True
1  Total    foo       True
2    bar    bar      False
```

Explanation:

```
In [50]: df.select_dtypes(['object']).sum(1)
Out[50]:
0    fooTotal
1    Totalfoo
2      barbar
dtype: object
```